# Change the color of empty table view cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I changed the color of cells from the storyboard (did not use any code) but as you can see in this image:

[image]

empty cells stay white as default. I want to change those empty cells to red also but I am having trouble figuring out.
I also in my code setting `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` with no success.

Comment: change tableView backGround Color

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just set tableView's backgroundColor: 
`yourTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Comment: oh...lol that was dumb of me. I was too focussed with cells haha (first time working with tables). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For others who like to use Storyboard, there's not a specific setting to set this, but in the Table View in Storyboard, you can go to the Identity Inspector, enter a "backgroundColor" and set it as the Color type in User Defined Runtime Attributes:

[image]

Not sure why this isn't a setting in storyboard, but this works!

Comment: thank you for a storyboard answer!! Why this still isn't a normal Attributes setting is beyond me

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 you can do this:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 2):

XCODE 8.2 AND SWIFT 3

For change the color for your tableview you can use two ways:

1. Use (TableViewController): You can call your TableView and change the color via code.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

   }
   ```
2. Use (StoryBoard): Select your TableView, and in the inspector tap Atributes then, in the down view find  View Section and chosse the color that you want from the Background atribute.

[image]